# Lifetime of function reference in Rust

Tags: rust, lifetime

So I'm trying to squeeze in callbacks to this enum variant (`Visual`) - which will be stored in a vector as seen within the struct `EntityComponents`:

```
enum Component {
    Position([f64; 2]),
    Visual(& Fn(Entity) -> ()),
}

struct EntityComponents {
    components_of_entity: HashMap<TypeId, Vec<Component>>,
}
```

However, Rust requires me to provide explicit lifetime parameters here.
My idea is that I want the function reference to live at least as long as its argument (the `Entity`), but I have no idea how the syntax for that would look like? Is it even possible?

The idea is that as long as an `Entity` has a `Visual` component, we can use this callback to render it!

Comment: Hi Kim, I change the references to code elements in your text to use the customary inline code formatting. I hope your are okay with that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things:

- You used `&Fn()` instead of `fn()`. The former is a trait object of the `Fn` trait, the latter is a good ol' function pointer. While the former is more general (in particular, it supports closures), it's rather unusual to store a reference to a closure that lives somewhere else.

  - Therefore, if you want to store closures as well, you'd probably use a `Box<Fn()>` which solves your lifetime problems.
  - If you don't care about closures, but just want to save function pointer, you can simply write `Visual(fn(Entity)),`. Function pointer always have a static lifetime. So this solves your lifetime problems as well.
  - But what if you really want to store a reference to an `Fn` trait object, which lives somewhere else? The solution depends on *where* it lives:
  - **In `Entity`**: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct/32300133#32300133)
  - **somehere else**: use a lifetime `<'a>`
- You wrote `Fn(Entity) -> ()`. The `-> ()` is always useless, you can omit it.

Comment: I'm positive a simple function pointer will work, thanks for clearing that up!